# Wpf apply datagrid templates

Tags: wpf

In my page I have a datagrid on which I would apply different templates, for example a template based on my custom type, so each custom have different number of columns.
Basically I would do this (pseudo code):

```
<Datagrid>
    <DataGridTemplates>
        <DataGridTemplate name="A">
            <DataGridTemplate.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Firstname" Binding="{Binding Firstname}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Lastname="{Binding Lastname}" />
            </DataGridTemplate.Columns>
        </DataGridTemplates

        <DataGridTemplate name="B">
            <DataGridTemplate.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Firstname" Binding="{Binding Firstname}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Lastname="{Binding Lastname}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Lastname="{Binding Address}" />
            </DataGridTemplate.Columns>
        </DataGridTemplates     
    <DataGridTemplates>
</Datagrid>
```

So based on some conditions, I would want to use DataGridTemplate A instead of B. How can I achieve a task like this?

Comment: You can use triggers and based on some condition you select which DataGrid to show. Search for triggers in wpf.

Answer (score 0):

Ali Beyit I think he wants to to choose the templates, not the grid to display. I think he has just one datagrid and several templates. I dunno if you can choose a template with triggers